# why do some directories have .uuid directory in a directory?

Tags: debian, filesystems, ext4, uuid

I have seen this quite a few times. In some random directories there is usually a .uuid file or directory therein. The directories are nothing special so as to speak. They are mostly random media files or files I have downloaded from somewhere or the other. Then why do these uuid files exist. The filesystem is ext4 and am using Debian buster.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with ext4, those files must be created by some application.  You could try using `file <path_to_file.uuid>` to see what kind of file it thinks this is.

Answer (score 12):

Do the random files include any **font files**, or files with a filename suffix matching those of any font file types? And does your desktop environment include a tool or library that would produce a preview of font files, or a custom icon for them?

`fontconfig` creates `.uuid` files in directories like `~/.fontconfig`. I guess some sort of font previewer might be doing its job by invoking `fontconfig` with a custom directory, and thus cause the `.uuid` files be dropped into directories where possible font files exist.

Comment: ah, that might be possibility as some of the files or media files where I have it do have subtitles sometimes although they are in .srt format, but maybe fontconfig might be doing something with that. Is there anyway to know more ?